# Executing a PHP Script Within Qt Application

Tags: php, c++, qt, qprocess

I'm developing a Qt application where I need to execute a PHP script. Despite the PHP file being located in the same directory as the project files, I receive an error when trying to run the script using `QProcess`. Here's the snippet causing the issue:

```cpp
this->getMined.start("php", QStringList() << "get_cexio_BTC.php");
this->getMined.waitForFinished();
QByteArray output = getMined.readAll();
```

When I run the application, I get the following error:

> Could not open input file: get_cexio_BTC.php

Is there something I'm overlooking in the `QProcess` setup that could be causing this file path issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if `php` is not found in the path, or didn't get loaded into the environment variables that `QProcess` is using, you could get an error like that.

Try printing out the environment variables:

```
qDebug() << "Process Environment" << myProcess.getProcessEnvironment().toStringList();
```

If under the `PATH` variable it doesn't mention the location of `php.exe`, it will fail.

You may need to specify `php.exe` instead of just `php`.  If it is being found correctly, then you should be able to see the usage statement of the php command when it isn't ran with any input file.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php

If that isn't the issue, then make sure that you are in the working directory that you think you are.

```
system("dir");
```

or

```
qDebug() << "current path" << QDir::currentPath();
```

You can change the current working directory in code, or specify it for a specific process or you can go and change it from Qt's Project Settings > Run > Working Directory.

And if you didn't already, be sure to check/print out the error string of your `QProcess` instance when it isn't doing what you want it to do.

```
qDebug() << "error string?" << myProcess.errorString();
```

And make sure you know to use forward slashes and quotes where appropriate.  If you have an unquoted command line argument/filename, it may see spaces in your path as another option to process.

And lastly if you are on Windows 8 and you are accessing something on a network drive, you have to run a net use command to be able to access those paths from the commandline, even if they are mapped and working in Windows explorer.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The error message seems to come from *php*, since it talks about input file. So, indeed, wrong working directory seems like the reason, as there's no absolute path given.

Answer (score 1):

You can use QNetworkAccessManager to access a page on localhost to trigger the included PHP script.

for example if you have the following php page in your htdocs directory: test.php

```
// test.php
echo("hello world");
```

you can access your page : `http://localhost/test.php`

```
QUrl url("http://localhost/test.php");
QNetworkAccessManager nam;
QNetworkReply* reply = nam.get(QNetworkRequest(url));
```